# How to simulate UDP issues to develop a reliable application?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm training with UDP data transfer based on this [this](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#datagram) guide.

I know about issues with UDP and author constantly reminds about them but the example applications work flawlessly. Even if I launch one communication partner on a remote VPS, I still have no package loss.
How to simulate UPD package loss to be able to test and develop at least somewhat reliable client-server pair?

Comment: You can also look at https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/ ... btw a simple google search would've found you these

Comment: @AhmedMasud yes, that's it, thanks.